# Ranking variables with conditions

Tags: r, ranking, ranking-functions

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(store       = LETTERS[1:8],
                 sales       = c(  9, 128,  54,  66,  23, 132,  89,  70),
                 successRate = c(.80, .25, .54, .92, .85, .35, .54, .46))
```

I want to rank the stores according to `successRate`, with ties going to the store with more sales, so first I do this (just to make visualization easier):

```
df <- df[order(-df$successRate, -df$sales), ]
```

In order to actually create a ranking variable, I do the following:

```
df$rank <- ave(df$successRate, FUN = function(x) rank(-x, ties.method='first'))
```

So `df` looks like this:

```
  store sales successRate rank
4     D    66        0.92    1
5     E    23        0.85    2
1     A     9        0.80    3
7     G    89        0.54    4
3     C    54        0.54    5
8     H    70        0.46    6
6     F   132        0.35    7
2     B   128        0.25    8
```

The problem is I don't want small stores to be part of the ranking. Specifically, **I want stores with less than 50 sales not to be ranked**. So this is how I define `df$rank` instead:

```
df$rank <- ifelse(df$sales < 50, NA,
                  ave(df$successRate, FUN = function(x) rank(-x, ties.method='first')))
```

The problem is that even though this correctly removes stores E and A, it doesn't reassign the rankings they were occupying. `df` looks like this now:

```
  store sales successRate rank
4     D    66        0.92    1
5     E    23        0.85   NA
1     A     9        0.80   NA
7     G    89        0.54    4
3     C    54        0.54    5
8     H    70        0.46    6
6     F   132        0.35    7
2     B   128        0.25    8
```

I've experimented with conditions inside and outside `ave()`, but I can'r get R to do what I want! **How can I get it to rank the stores like this?**

```
  store sales successRate rank
4     D    66        0.92    1
5     E    23        0.85   NA
1     A     9        0.80   NA
7     G    89        0.54    2
3     C    54        0.54    3
8     H    70        0.46    4
6     F   132        0.35    5
2     B   128        0.25    6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super easy to do with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

# do the ordering you like (note, could also use setkey to do this faster)
dt = dt[order(-successRate, -sales)]

dt[sales >= 50, rank := .I]
dt
#   store sales successRate rank
#1:     D    66        0.92    1
#2:     E    23        0.85   NA
#3:     A     9        0.80   NA
#4:     G    89        0.54    2
#5:     C    54        0.54    3
#6:     H    70        0.46    4
#7:     F   132        0.35    5
#8:     B   128        0.25    6
```

If you must do it in `data.frame`, then after your preferred order, run:

```
df$rank <- NA
df$rank[df$sales >= 50] <- seq_len(sum(df$sales >= 50))
```

Comment: Awesome! I wonder if there's solution that doesn't require using `data.table`.

Comment: @wleoncio there is, see edit; I don't use `data.frame` anymore though and the above is just one in a multitude of examples of why :)

Comment: Nice edit, but the `data.frame` solution is not ordering by successRate, but by sales. ;)

Comment: @wleoncia those two lines assume data is already ordered as per OP

Comment: Oh, right, I got things mixed up here. I confess I've never used `data.table` and I'm a little resistant to use it in old scripts, but I've been reading so many wonderful things about it I'll study the package and try to apply it on my future projects. Thanks for the help!